# when the numerator is less than the denominator

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

when the numerator is less than the denominator the result is always between 0 and 1?
for example if I have a number like
`x/y where x<y` then the result will be between 0 and 1 always? Is there a proof for this?

Comment: If the numerator is negative it could be between -1 and 0, e.g. $\displaystyle-\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Assuming both $x$ and $y$ are positive, and we have existence of inverses, then $x < y \implies x \cdot \frac{1}{y} < y \cdot \frac{1}{y} \implies \frac{x}{y} < 1$.

Comment: so basically depending on it's sign it would be either -1->0 or 0->1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $x$ and $y$ are positive, you have $0<x<y$, so $\frac1y>0$, and $$0\cdot\frac1y<x\cdot\frac1y<y\cdot\frac1y\;,$$ which on simplification becomes

$$0<\frac{x}y<1\;.$$

Comment: so that is also the proof. Looks great thank you.

Comment: @themhz: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

If $0 < x < y$, then by dividing all three numbers by the positive quantity $y$, you have
$$
0 < \frac{x}{y} < 1.
$$